# ActivateItem not working in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro for MVVM. In my MainView (shell), I have two controls. One hosts a RibbonView and another ContentControl which loads contents depending on the RibbonView menu selection. Here is the MainView (shell)

**MainView (shell)**

```
<Window x:Class="HotelReservation.Main.Views.MainView">
    <DockPanel>

        <ContentControl x:Name="RibbonView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**RibbonView**

```
<Ribbon Margin="0,-20,0,0">
    <RibbonTab Header="Room Band">
        <RibbonGroup>
            <RibbonButton Label="List" x:Name="RoomBandMain"
                             LargeImageSource="/HotelReservation.Global;component/Images/room-band-list-icon.png">
            </RibbonButton>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

**RibbonViewModel**

```
public class RibbonViewModel : Conductor<object> {

    public void RoomBandMain() { //Load in ActiveItem of MainView
        ActivateItem(container.GetExportedValue<RoomBandMainViewModel>());
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I am trying to load **RoomBandMainViewModel** in the `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>` The issue is that it is not loaded and I get a blank screen even though `ActivateItem(container.GetExportedValue<RoomBandMainViewModel>())` code runs. I think that the `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>` exists not in **RibbonView** but its parent **MainView**, and hence the ActivateItem doesn't work.

How to resolve this issue.

**Edit:**

I had to set the DataContext of the `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>` to RibbonViewModel, so that `ActiveItem` is now property of RibbonViewModel and not MainViewModel. **MainViewModel** looks like below

So the MainView (shell) is now as follows

```
<Window x:Class="Conductor_Main.Views.MainView">

    <DockPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="RibbonView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green"  
               DataContext="{Binding RibbonView}">

            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Now the `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />` actually belongs to the RibbonViewModel.

Comment: This looks like what i am doing, have to take a closer look. Will answer later.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are doing here in a project. Perhaps there is some information missing about you mainwindow / shellview. In my case the ShellViewModel is the conductor, so it has an Activeitem. The windows I want to show there are childwindows of that mainwindow. And it works like a charm.

Comment: @MareInfinitus, The MainView (shown in question) is the shell view for my application. It has two content controls RibbonView and ActiveItem. But the ActivateItem is not in MainViewModel. It is part of RibbonViewModel which is child of MainViewModel. In short how do I activate a control in RibbonViewModel, when the control is in MainView.

Comment: So you want to use parts of your RibbonView to be shown in your MainView also? The ActiveItem is outside of your RibbonView and Child of the MainView. And you want some kind of recycling here?

Comment: @MareInfinitus, I just changed the DataContext of the ContentControl which has ActiveItem to the RibbonViewModel, so that ActiveItem is now part of RibbonViewModel and loaded correctly. Please see my  edit to the question.

Comment: According to your code it is not. You have one `ContentControl` which is the `RibbonView` and another `ContentControl` which is the `ActiveItem`. Your `MainWindow` shall be the `Conductor` here. Please update your XAML so that it shows what you have in the comments here.

Comment: @MareInfinitus The DataContext of second content control is set to RibbonView. Look at line <Grid ...> in the updated MainView.xaml (shell). You can see that its (and hence second ContentControl's) dataContext is set to RibbonView. I have already updated the Shell (MainView.xaml) to reflect the change in the DataContext of the second control.

Comment: Right now I do not have the time, but will look at this tommorow. I am sure that this kind of thing immediately works. Can you perhaps upload a bigger example somewhere, like github?

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is some kind of lifecycle of your windows. This has to be handled by the parent window of your `ActiveItem`.

The way to get this done the caliburn.micro way is to have a Conductor above the `ActiveItem`. In your case this is the `MainWindow`.

Your `RibbonViewModel` can be a Conductor, too. But only for it's own children. There can be more than one conductor.

From [the caliburn documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)

> Once you introduce the notion of a Screen Activation Lifecycle into
>   your application, you need some way to enforce it. This is the role of
>   the ScreenConductor. When you show a screen, the conductor makes sure
>   it is properly activated.

Which is quite a direct way of saying: If you have activation / life cycle, then use a conductor.

Comment: see the comment I posted to my question